# Visual Studio 2012 uploading image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, upload

How do I upload an image in a WPF application written using Visual Studio 2012?

In 2010, there was a button that you clicked on the source property for the directory and you'd just go to the path of the image. That is not the case for 2012, so does anyone know how to do it.

Comment: can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve please.

Comment: I placed a picture box on a WPF and when I went to the source property of the picturebox, I didn't see a button to search my directory to put the picture in the picture box. I had to copy and paste the path(C://folder/pics/pic.jpg) which seems counter intuitive than how it use to be.

Comment: ok, so your looking for the small dialogue button to open the dialogue box?, and when you say picture box, are you talking an Image control and then you put the location in the source?

Comment: @Simon Price yes exactly that. And is it called image control instead of picture box in WPF. My mistake if it is, but the problem is still the same. I'll add the pics to my resource folder today and see if that works.  Any reason as to why they changed that?

Comment: I just think thats the difference between winforms and WPF, they are massively different from each other in some respects, and similar in others.

Answer (score 0):

With WPF, there isnt a PictureBox control, but there is an Image control, and then in Properties, under the common group of properties there is a source drop down list.  If your image is not added to your solution, then this will be blank.

Create a Resources Folder if one doesnt exist, and then add an existing item, ie your image then go back to the source drop down list and the image will be there.